# Script for changing DB values of columns with different names from several different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Kinda new to Database scripting,

1. I want a script that will show me 10's of columns from 10's of columns.
2. Script for changing values of 10's columns from 10's of columns.

I know I can use Select statement but is that best practice ?

**Edit**

I tired

```
Select

table1.column1,
table1.column2,
table2.column1
    ......
    table100.column100 FROM    table1,table2,.....table100;
```

> but getting this error
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'table1'.

**Answer**

Few table were deleted by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.Selecting 10's of columns from 10's of columns -- select * from tablename is good way.
But this is not good when you consider the query for performance point of view.If your reuirement is to get all the columns of a table then you can use select * from tablename.

2.This is quite obvious that you have to use all 10 columns if u have to change their values.
UPDATE tablename SETcol1=value1,
       col1=value1,
       col1=value1,
       .....
```